# Formatting a pandas datetime object from [HH:MM:ss] to [HH:MM]

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a `pandas` `DataFrame` with 4 columns (Time,T1,T2,T3) and their respective values obtained throughout the day using a custom made temperature data logger. The `Time` column has the format [HH:MM:ss] but I would like to change this to [HH:MM] (truncate the seconds) for plotting purposes. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Here is my code:  (Using Python 3.6)

```
import pandas as pd  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel('water_data_full_load.xlsx'))  
df.drop("Date", axis = 1, inplace =True)  
df.set_index('Time',inplace =True)  

df.rename_axis({"T1": "Twall", "T2":"Twater", "T3":"Tsurr"}, axis=1, inplace=True)

df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda x: x[:5])  
graph = df[['Twall','Twater','Tsurr']].plot()  
plt.xticks(rotation =45)  
plt.ylabel('Temperature ($^\circ$C)')  
plt.xlabel('Time of the day (HH:MM)')  
plt.show(graph)
```

[Please refer to this image for the current DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpDK0.png)

[image]

Comment: Do you want to truncate the seconds or round? eg: Does 11:34:31 become 11:34 or 11:35 ?

Comment: I'm impressed by the answers, but it looks like they're working uphill against your lack of posted code, data or expected results - any of those things would make it much more likely that you get a useful answer.

Comment: I've updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [41]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['11:07:00','12:06:00','13:17:00'], 'Twall':[10,20,30]}).set_index('Time')

In [42]: df
Out[42]:
          Twall
Time
11:07:00     10
12:06:00     20
13:17:00     30

In [43]: df.index = df.index.astype(str).str.rsplit(':',n=1).str[0]

In [44]: df
Out[44]:
       Twall
Time
11:07     10
12:06     20
13:17     30
```

---

Demo (vectorized approach) - for truncating seconds from a column of `datetime` dtype:

```
In [46]: df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2017-01-01', freq='99S', periods=10), columns=['date'])

In [47]: df
Out[47]:
                 date
0 2017-01-01 00:00:00
1 2017-01-01 00:01:39
2 2017-01-01 00:03:18
3 2017-01-01 00:04:57
4 2017-01-01 00:06:36
5 2017-01-01 00:08:15
6 2017-01-01 00:09:54
7 2017-01-01 00:11:33
8 2017-01-01 00:13:12
9 2017-01-01 00:14:51


In [49]: df['date'] = df['date'].values.astype('<M8[m]')

In [50]: df
Out[50]:
                 date
0 2017-01-01 00:00:00
1 2017-01-01 00:01:00
2 2017-01-01 00:03:00
3 2017-01-01 00:04:00
4 2017-01-01 00:06:00
5 2017-01-01 00:08:00
6 2017-01-01 00:09:00
7 2017-01-01 00:11:00
8 2017-01-01 00:13:00
9 2017-01-01 00:14:00
```

Comment: using your updated code, I get this error: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values (i.e. inferred_type is 'string', 'unicode' or 'mixed')

Comment: @FrancodeJager, what is the output of `print(df.index.dtype)`?

Comment: the output of `print(df.index.dtype)` is given as `object` .

Comment: @FrancodeJager, and the output of `print(df.index[0].dtype)`?

Comment: I get the following output: AttributeError: 'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Time': ['22:05:00','22:06:00','22:07:00']})

df['Time_to_plot'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda x: x[:5])

print df


       Time Time_to_plot
0  22:05:00        22:05
1  22:06:00        22:06
2  22:07:00        22:07
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. One issue: I keep on getting a KeyError: 'Time' and I am unsure why or how to fix it. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: do you really have a column named `Time` ?.